# Why is $rdθ$ equal to $dlcosφ$ (Derivation of Ampere's law.)

Tags: calculus, geometry

In the diagram, it suggests that $rdθ$ is equal to the line which bisects at $90$ degrees. When I draw it out (see my diagram) it suggests that the arc should have a length greater than $rdθ$. Could someone point out what my incorrect assumptions are, if any.

Thank you :)

Image from the textbook.:

[image]

Diagram I drew:

[image]

Comment: Note that this is all done for _very small_ changes in $\theta$, and if the change in $\theta$ is small, then the differences between the different possible versions of $rd\theta$ become even smaller (those differences are of the order $(rd\theta)^2$). So it doesn't really matter which of the two lines $rd\theta$ is orthogonal to (or if it makes an isosceles triangle, or if we're measuring the arc), the approximation $dl\cdot \cos \phi$ works either way.

Comment: @Arthur You should write this up as an answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. I thought it might be to do with the fact that it was incredibly small, but I wanted to properly visualize it, which I guess is practically impossible for human's. Diagrams can be quite misleading in some physics examples I'm finding. Thanks again.